# how to deal with error at activating environment?

Tags: python, conda

When I try to activate a conda environment, these messages popped up, and the cmd window closed automatically. How to deal with this?

```
C:\Users\a>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1 

C:\Users\a>SET MSSdk=1 

C:\Users\a>SET platform= 

C:\Users\a>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true" 

C:\Users\a>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true" 

C:\Users\a>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" ) 

C:\Users\a>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B" 

C:\Users\a>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=" ) 

C:\Users\a>if "" == "" (
ECHO "Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - exiting"  
exit 1 
) 
"Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - exiting"
```

Comment: How did you try to activate it? `conda activate`? Or something else?

Comment: *Is* Visual Studio installed (as the error implies it is not)? It should be pretty straightforward by reading that code to infer the environment variables and registry keys you could use to point to a valid installation, if you had one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I used activate XXX on windows

Comment: Thanks Charles, Well,  it worked fine until I installed keras on that environment. I don't need VS, and don't want to install it either, is there a way to bypass ?

Comment: Apparently, keras requires Visual Studio. Probably not a way to work around it...

Comment: This is due to https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/aggregate/tree/master/vs2015 this recipe. It seems this anaconda recipe is struggling to find where vcvarsall.bat in various vs2017 editions

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you (the problem occured after installing keras in one enviroment). I fixed this problem by deleting the folder 'etc' under Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu(win10).

Answer (score 0):

using solution from  [Anaconda prompt closes immediately - the system was unable to find the specified registry key or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635462/anaconda-prompt-closes-immediately-the-system-was-unable-to-find-the-specified)

i use a command pip uninstall vs2015_win-64 
then 
SET KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
to solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem raised by vs2015_win-64 (dependency of pymc3 and etc.), so I just deleted vs2015_compiler_vars.bat

```sh
rm ~/scoop/apps/miniconda3/current/envs/kaggle/etc/conda/activate.d/vs2015_compiler_vars.bat
```

Then, everything goes well now.