# Anaconda prompt closes immediately - the system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda

I'm having an issue with the Anaconda prompt.

Everything was find until I created a new environment with [PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/) in it.

The usual way : `conda create -n myenv`

and then, after I activated it : `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3`

For some reason the packages weren't installed so I deleted the environment.

Now, I'm getting this error, see picture here :

[image]

The last "error : error" message translates to : "the system was unable to find the specified registry key or value".

Now what's weird is that when I start the application from the navigator instead of the prompt, I can access my envs and launch my notebook or visual code studio from there but for the base environment which doesn't work.

**But** trying to open the prompt closes it immediately, I believe it is accessing "base", the default env. Also, from the navigator I'm unable to launch a notebook from the "base" env.

Picture here :

[image]

Though as I said, other environments are fine.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ? I can't access the prompt because of it, I was just lucky enough to grab it and take a screenshot, it closes immediatlely otherwise.

P.S : I use Windows 10 on a Lenovo laptop, Python 3.7 and never had the issue before today.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This just happened to me as well after updating all of my packages. I did some digging and the error is coming from `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\etc\conda\activate.d\vs2015_compiler_vars.bat`

This file has your last line before your error:

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "%VSREGKEY%" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%%B"
```

And if you run `reg query "%VSREGKEY%" /v InstallDir`on your Windows command prompt, you'll get the same error you see on your Anaconda prompt.

I tried making some changes to handle this error but even if you manage to get past that you will likely end up getting this error : `Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - exiting` This is happening because the `VSINSTALLDIR` bash variable is meant for finding the `vcvarsall.bat` file later in the script but now that directory shows up as empty.

I wasn't able to find any `vcvarsall.bat` file in my system, likely because I haven't installed Visual Studio which this file is meant for. One solution is to install Visual Studio (2015 version) and make sure you have the `InstallDir` registry key for it. But I didn't do this since VS is a pretty big program (7 GB I think) that I have no use for that at the moment.

**The solution I took is to simply delete** `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\etc\conda`. I created a new miniconda installation (in a different path) and saw that this directory did not exist in it for whatever reason so I imagine that reinstalling would do the same thing. I deleted the second installation and the first one is still working so I doubt there's any dependencies issues involved. That said, **I have no idea what that script was meant for and do not know what consequences may come without it.** Full disclosure.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did end  up reinstalling Anaconda completely and Visual studio code, I don't have that issue anymore but I made sure I installed only the strict necessary on the (base) root environment s.t I don't corrupt anything anymore. I don't get what it's doing either, sounds like it's asking for some sort of key or expecting some confirmation from visual studio code?

Comment: My hypothesis is that this `vcvarsall.bat` file is used to integrate the conda environment into Visual Studio. It can deleted without issue so it seems to be optional. And from what I've seen by looking up the script, it seems pretty common for other applications to use it.

Comment: Nice; I'll mark it as fixed and maybe add an issue to their github, thanks for your help!

Comment: @DiogenicOrder Hi, I am also facing it. After reinstalling along with VS Code, still, the issue persists. Did you come across any other solutions in these years after this post? TIA

Comment: @DiogenicOrder pip install resolved this issue. :-) Thanks.

Comment: @xkcvk2511 I found out a few days later and completely forgot to add it here, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 10):

After installing keras I got the same problem.

I checked **Anaconda Navigator > Environments** for a related package. I found vs2015_win-64 package that said

> Activation and version verification of MSVC 14 (VS 2015) compiler

I was not able to remove the package using the Anaconda Navigator.

Anaconda prompt closes immediately after the error message but there is enough time to stop the command execution with **Ctrl + C** + **Enter**. Now I was able to use the Anaconda prompt to remove the package.

Anaconda prompt:

```
conda uninstall vs2015_win-64
```

Comment: I was able to delete the vs2015_win-64 package from my anaconda navigator and now I can activate my environment.

Comment: This also fixes for me when using `VSCode` , [when trying to use "Interactive" mode of Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) My message was more verbose, mentions a "Shell" : `Activating Python 3.7.1 64-bit ('base': conda) to run Jupyter failed with Error: StdErr from ShellExec, ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.`

Answer (score 0):

I got ran out of this by uninstalling the `theano` package. I confronted this log right after installing the `theano` package, So I assumed that the root of the problem was related to this package. After uninstalling it using `conda uninstall theano`, everything got Ok, and I don't see this log anymore!