# Anaconda Prompt closes authomatically

Tags: python, anaconda, prompt, navigator

I have problem opening Anaconda Prompt, as it closes automatically. The problem appeared when I have installed pymc3, I even uninstall pymc3 to see if it works again or not, but the problem was not fixed. Before that, I could have open Spyder or Jupyter from Anaconda navigator, but now I can not. Does anyone know what is the problem?

I took a screenshot from the Anaconda prompt when for one second it appears and closes it shows the following:

[image]

Comment: How about re-installing Anaconda?

Comment: conda uninstall vs2015_win-64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635462/anaconda-prompt-closes-immediately-the-system-was-unable-to-find-the-specified