# Specified configuration type is missing when launching Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda

Since recently i have an issue when launching the Anaconda prompt. It states that VCvarsall.bat is missing. I looked at some other sources to solve this issue (https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/) but the issue remained. I dont know how to handle this. Whenever i open Anaconda prompt i get the following screen:

`````
C:\Users\Name>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\Users\Name>del temp.txt

C:\Users\Name>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\Name>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)

C:\Users\Name>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\Name>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\Name>SET platform=

C:\Users\Name>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\Name>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\Users\Name>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\Users\Name>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Name>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\" )

C:\Users\Name>if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\" == "" (
ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)

C:\Users\Name>echo "Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
"Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"

C:\Users\Name>SET "VS_VERSION=14.0"

C:\Users\Name>SET "VS_MAJOR=14"

C:\Users\Name>SET "VS_YEAR=2015"

C:\Users\Name>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"

C:\Users\Name>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"

C:\Users\Name>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\vcruntime140.dll"

C:\Users\Name>set "CFLAGS= -MD -GL"

C:\Users\Name>set "CXXFLAGS= -MD -GL"

C:\Users\Name>set "LDFLAGS_SHARED= -LTCG ucrt.lib"

C:\Users\Name>set "CXX=cl.exe"

C:\Users\Name>set "CC=cl.exe"

C:\Users\Name>IF /I [] == [win-64] (set "folder=x64" )  else (set "folder=x86" )

C:\Users\Name>for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\*1*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (10) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A

C:\Users\Name>if "10" == "8.1" set win=10

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (8.1) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A

C:\Users\Name>if "8.1" == "8.1" set win=8.1

C:\Users\Name>for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\*1*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (10) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A

C:\Users\Name>if "10" == "10" set win=10

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (8.1) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A

C:\Users\Name>if "8.1" == "10" set win=8.1

C:\Users\Name>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

C:\Users\Name>if "10" == "10" (
for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do set last=%A
 set "sdk_bin_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\!last!\x86"
)  else (set "sdk_bin_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86" )

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (10.0.14393.0) do set last=%A

C:\Users\Name>set last=10.0.14393.0

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (10.0.15063.0) do set last=%A

C:\Users\Name>set last=10.0.15063.0

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (10.0.16299.0) do set last=%A

C:\Users\Name>set last=10.0.16299.0

C:\Users\Name>for %A in (10.0.17134.0) do set last=%A

C:\Users\Name>set last=10.0.17134.0

C:\Users\Name>endlocal   & set "PATH=C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Users\Name\Desktop\ffmpeg-20190920-2f87c9f-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86"

C:\Users\Name>IF NOT "" == "" (
set "INCLUDE=;"
 set "LIB=;"
 set "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=;"
)

C:\Users\Name>SET "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"

C:\Users\Name>CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the
configuration might not be installed.

(base) C:\Users\Name>````

Thanks for any help!
`````

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by following post ([Anaconda prompt closes immediately - the system was unable to find the specified registry key or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635462/anaconda-prompt-closes-immediately-the-system-was-unable-to-find-the-specified)): 
With following operation:

conda uninstall vs2015_win-64

Thanks,